# Similar to alt tag in WinForms controls

Tags: c#, .net

Maybe that's a noob question but is there a way to have an yellow tooltip alike web alt while using web browser in winform application controls such as checkBox or Button ?

Comment: There's a tooltip you can add to buttons etc. in WinForms - is that what you mean? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/tooltips.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
tooltip.SetToolTip(checkBox, "A tooltip on my checkBox");
tooltip.SetToolTip(button, "A tooltip on my button");
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a tooltip you can add to buttons etc. in WinForms - is that what you mean?

If so there's a [tutorial on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/tooltips.aspx). Basically you need this code:

```
private System.WinForms.ToolTip m_wndToolTip;

this.m_wndToolTip = new System.WinForms.ToolTip (this.components);

m_wndToolTip.SetToolTip (PictureButton, "Click Me!");
m_wndToolTip.SetToolTip (m_wndIntTextBox, "Enter Integer data type value.");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you press F4 you will get the controls options in that go to the bottom and you will find a tooltip option and give your message there and it appears when you run the application and you'll find the tooltip when you hover the mouse over the button or what ever it might be.

Answer (score 0):

You want a tooltip. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx).